# Error : iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)

Tags: android, iptables, android-source

I'm building a ROM from AOSP ICS, when i'm running it on emulator and trying to access the iptables it gives me the error as

```
iptables v1.4.11.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
```

What must be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel image does not contain the dependent modules for IPTABLES.

Please check your kernel build config files to see if iptables (netfilter, netlink etc) is enabled.

Comment: How to enable the module?

Answer (score 0):

ADB SHELL SU

change to root and try again